# 'the shipment email is not sent' message in order details

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this message in orders:

> Shipment #400001878 | Dec 10, 2017 4:55:20 PM (the shipment email is
>   not sent)

I use **myparcel** for shipment methods.
confirugation->sales emails->shipment->Yes

order email confirmation is sent to customers. How to debug this? please help
ps: Magento 1.9.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Setup a cronjob for your Magento because since Magento 1.9.1, all email are queued and sent from cron after some (cron is processed), now the emails are not being sent directly, or run your cron.php file from shell

```
php cron.php
```

Execute this command when you are in Magento installation directory.